# Concurrent threads accessing a singleton

Tags: java, multithreading

how does Java behave when it has thousands of threads accessing the same instance?

I am building an ERP and I am intending to create a Singleton so that it is able to do any kind of persistence (Insert, Update, Delete) in my base. This singleton will have no global variables other than the instance itself. It will have only its methods.

My question is that as I will centralize all ERP persistence on this single instance, this can become a bottleneck and a cause for slowness. Can this occur?
I'm talking about 500,000 simultaneous hits in this instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your singleton is immutable, multiple threads will use its methods concurrently without any degradation of latency.

Comment: So hits of millions of threads in a single instance that only has methods can never be a speed bottleneck?

Comment: That you use a singleton will not be a problem, million threads will be, but this is not related to your question.